# How to Call an Extjs store without creating an explicit instance of it

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an application which has is its first page build with different component.I am creating a  userStore instance on page load(main.js) I want to access userStore  in my header to get the firstname of user and display it on the header section.

```
Ext.create('store.User', {
    storeId : 'storeUser'
});
    Ext.define('OnlineApp.view.Main', {
    extend      : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype       : 'app-main',
    requires    : [
        'Ext.plugin.Viewport'

    ],
    controller  : 'main',
    viewModel   : 'main',
    layout      : 'border',
    padding     : '0 0 0 0',
    bodyStyle   : 'border:0',
    items       : [
        {
            xtype   : 'appHeader',
            region  : 'north'
        },
        {
            xtype       : 'tabpanel',
            region      : 'center',
            bodyPadding : 0,
            id          : 'contentPanel',
            reference   : 'contentPanel',
            layout      : 'card',
            border      : false,
            scrollable  : true,
            tabBar      : {
                hidden  : true
            },
            items       : [
                firstPage,
                contentFrame,

            ],

        },

        {
            xtype   : 'footer',
            region  : 'south'
        }
       ]
   });

** This is a Header file where I am trying to use the store below. Not sure what could be the best way to call store without creating a instance.**

      Ext.define('OnlineApp.view.Header', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype   : 'appHeader',
    id      : 'main-header',

    height  : 100,

    layout  : {
        type    : 'hbox',
        align   : 'middle'
    },
    initComponent: function() {

        this.items = [

            {
                xtype   : 'container',
                flex    : .55,
                layout  : {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align : 'right'
                },
                collapsible : false,
                padding : 5,
                items   : [
                    {
                        xtype   : 'container',
                        id      : 'app-header-user',
                        ui      : 'usp-plain-button',
                        layout  : {
                            type    : 'hbox',
                            align   : 'center'
                        },
                        items   : [
                           {
                               xtype : 'component',
                              html   : 'Welcome, <b>' + Ext.getStore('storeUser').data.firstname + '</b>'   **// I am trying to use the store getting fiest name as undefined.** 
                           },
                           {
                               xtype : 'gear-menu'
                           }
                        ]
                    },

            }
        ];
            this.callParent();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that you have correctly generated/defined store. You have `Ext.define('store.User')` somewhere. Otherwise you should use  `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{storeId: 'storeUser'});`

So `Ext.getStore('storeUser')` is returning store object in your header view. You can't just use `data.firstname` on it. Because [data property](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#property-data) in the store is Ext.util.Collection.

If you want to get data from your store you should use:

```
Ext.getStore('storeUser').getAt(0).get('firstname')
```

Where 0 is the index of the record in your store.

Btw in your case I would recommend you to use [Ext.Temaples](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Template.html) you can check the official [example here](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/platform/templates.html). Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20140355/1768843) is quite OK example on the stackoverflow.

Comment: In that case there must be something wrong with your store. Could you add code about your store? Because in the example code your store is empty.

Comment: Yes I have a store correctly defined . Also I tried to use Ext.getStore('storeUser').getAt(0).get('firstname'), i hit with an error  " Cannot read property 'get' of null"   However creating  explicit instance i get it working. I will try the template suggestion.                                                 Ext.create('store.User').load({
scope: this, callback: function(records, operation, success) {
 var headerObj=this.items.items[1].items.items[0].items.items[0];
  headerObj .setHtml('Welcome, <b>' + records[0].data.firstname + '</b>');} });

Comment: Ext.define('OnlineApp.store.User', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias  : 'store.User',
    model  : 'OnlineApp.model.User',
    autoLoad : true
});

Comment: Here is a model  Ext.define('Online.model.User', {
 extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',alias: 'model.User',fields[
         {name: 'accountNonLocked', type: 'boolean', convert: null},
         {name: 'firstname', type: 'string', convert: null},
         {name: 'lastname', type: 'string', convert: null},
 idProperty : 'username',autoLoad  : false,proxy: {
        type  : 'ajax', noCache: true,  method: 'POST',     
        url   : Online.Globals.getBaseURL()+'/getCurrentUser',  
        reader  : {type: 'json',  keepRawData : true}, }});

Comment: Even displaying in template will have the same error . As no data via store.

Comment: In that case, I think that there is a problem with the store itself.

Comment: Thats what i want to understand what is the problem . Because when i create a new instance of a store  i am able to get the data.